# Typescript breakpoints not being hit in Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

A couple of people have asked this question, and I have tried their solutions and they haven't worked for me, as shown by the "Solutions I've tried" section below.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. From VS 2017 Professional, create a new NodeJS Blank Console Application. I named it "Testing".
   [image]
2. Set a breakpoint on the `console.log`, and click the green arrow.
   [image]
3. No breakpoint ends up being hit. The screen flashes with the running program, but the red breakpoint circle changes to just an outline (to indicate that no symbols could be loaded).

**Solutions I've tried:**

- This Debugging option is already checked:
  [image]
- This project properties option is already checked:
  [image]

**What is going wrong? How can I get VS to hit a breakpoint please?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating from Visual Studio version 15.7 to 15.9 has solved this problem, and not breakpoints are correctly being hit in the Typescript files.